# understanding the python dictionary syntax

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax

What is the difference between the following two syntax for a python dictionary?

The first one gives me an error, the second doesn't.

The key is text, just a description, and the value is a variable.

```
dict["external_email_address"] =email

dict{"url":profile_url};
```

Comment: The second will not run. What error are you getting from the first?

Comment: What Error do you have?

Comment: The first will `NameError` because email isn't defined.  If it is, it will `TypeError` because you can't index the builtin `dict()`.  If you called it (e.g.) `my_dict` it will again `NameError` because that's not defined.  The second will `SyntaxError` regardless because you can't have an opening brace following a token like that (missing `=`?).  Flagging to close because there is just not enough context.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you're trying to create a dictionary or access an existing one.  You should avoid using [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict) as the name of a variable (if that's what you're doing) and your first line of code may just be accessing the predefined `dict` which is not what you want.  Your second line doesn't look like valid Python syntax at all and gives me a syntax error.

Try this in Python 2.7:

```
a = {}
b = dict()
c = {"aa":1}
d = dict(aa=1)
a["aa"] = 1
b["aa"] = 1
print a["aa"]
print b["aa"]
print c["aa"]
print d["aa"]
print a
print b
print c
print d
```

`a` and `b` show are two ways of creating an empty [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).  `c` and `d` show two ways of creating a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) with some keys in it.  Following are some basic use cases.

Comment: @Christian I'm hoping the OP can answer his own unclear question by trying this out.